# Mirror android watch in windows PC

Tags: android, mirroring, vysor

I would like to know, if there is any possibility to mirror my android watch device in real time using android studio?

Using  [Vysor](https://vysor.io/), I'm able to do mirroring in android phone and tablet, not with android watch.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to achieve same thing and I have done it by following below link,

https://rominirani.com/tutorial-cast-your-android-wear-screen-to-all-5265c392007b

Comment: Thanks,will try this